# Liquibase changeSet with runAlways not executed by liquibase.update

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I am struggling to reload data from a .csv file using `runAlways="true"` attribute. My goal is to rewrite(update) application version read from `app_version.csv` file in case the value changed. If changed, I use Liquibase API to run `liquibase.update(..)` which should trigger the changeSet that has  section.

My pom.xml:

```
...
        <!-- Persistance DEPS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

Application.properties:

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
spring.liquibase.contexts=prod
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
# H2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/author-db/testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

DB table `global_settings` (using H2 in file at the moment, pk="id"):

```
ID | APP_KEY    |   APP_VALUE    | CREATED_BY | CREATED_DATE           | LAST_MODIFIED_BY | LAST_MODIFIED_DATE  
1   app-version   4.3.3-SNAPSHOT     system     2020-01-21 16:11:10.009     system                     null
```

The .xml file containing the changeSet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

  <changeSet id="app_version" author="author">
    <loadData file="db/app_version.csv" separator=";"
      tableName="global_settings">
      <column name="id" type="numeric"/>
      <column name="created_date" type="timestamp"/>
      <column name="last_modified_date" type="timestamp"/>
    </loadData>
  </changeSet>

  <changeSet id="update_app_version" author="author" runAlways="true">
    <loadUpdateData file="db/app_version.csv" separator=";" tableName="global_settings"
      primaryKey="id">
      <column name="id" type="numeric"/>
      <column name="created_date" type="timestamp"/>
      <column name="last_modified_date" type="timestamp"/>
    </loadUpdateData>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Contents of the `app_version.csv`file:

```
id;app_key;app_value;created_by;last_modified_by
1;app-version;@project.version@;system;system
```

Java code used to run:

```
inside main spring boot class
...

Optional<GlobalSettings> appSettings =  globalSettingsRepository.findOneByAppKey("app-version"); --> value = 4.3.3-SNAPSHOT
appSettings.get().setValue("4.3.2"); --> value = 4.3.2
globalSettingsRepository.save(appSettings.get());
runLiquibaseUpdate(); --> value = 4.3.2

--------------
public void runLiquibaseUpdate() {
    Database database;
    Connection connection;
    Liquibase liquibase;
    try {
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"),
          env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"),
          env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
      database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));

      DatabaseChangeLog changeLog = new DatabaseChangeLog(env.getProperty("spring.liquibase.change-log"));
      liquibase = new Liquibase(changeLog, new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);
      liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
    } catch (SQLException | LiquibaseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

My intention was this: first changeSet (id="app_version") loads the data from .csv file, works. After `runLiquibaseUpdate` method is run, per my understanding (please correct me if I'm wrong), it should trigger the changeSet(id="update_app_version") due to `runAlways="true"` and the value in the database should change to the initial value found in .csv file, but it doesn't.

So far, I have not been able to pinpoint the cause of the problem, logs are not showing anything after method is finished.

If my understanding is wrong and this is not doable, I kindly ask for an advice on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The changelog you have defined in your `Application.properties` is only valid for the `prod` context but you have called liquibase in no-context mode:

```
spring.liquibase.contexts=prod
```

So either remove the entry in the properties file or provide it to liquibase:

```
 liquibase.update(new Contexts("prod), new LabelExpression());
```

Comment: Tried it, but the result is the same.